# c++ dynamic array initialization crash

Tags: c++, arrays, crash, dynamic-arrays

I have the following code where i call a function and create a dynamic array of ints and then fill that array with an algorithm

**main.cpp**

```
...
int main(void){

    srand((long) 1234567);

    callFunction1();

    return 0;

}
```

**functions.h**

```
...
    int *A;
    int N;

    //prototype
    void callFunction2();

    void callFunction1(){

         int choice;
         cin >> choice;

         while (choice != 2){

               callFunction2();

               cin >> choice;
         }

    }

    void callFunction2(){

         cout << "Enter array size" << endl;
         cin >> N;

         A = new int[N];
         A[0] = 0;
         A[1] = 1;

         for (int i=2;i<=N;i++){
             A[i] = A[i-1] + A[i-2];
         }

    }
```

So the above code will work most of the time but some times it will crash on the line where i initialize the array

**A = new int[N];**

What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: You're going out of bounds on your "array".

Comment: You either enter a number for N that is less or equal 1, or you enter a number for N that is so large that allocating the array would consume more than the memory available (mind possible memory fragmentation, too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing `A` out of bounds here:

```
for (int i=2;i<=N;i++){
         A[i] = ....
```

`A` can only be indexed from `0` up to `N-1`, i.e. in the range **[0, N)**.

Comment: Thats what i was given... Αi = Ai-1 + Ai-2 for i = 2…n

Comment: @fxuser And that is wrong and may cause a segmentation violation. So fix it. You have to make a distinction between the expression you just posted and the indices of an array.

Comment: @fxuser it would make more sense to change the condition of the for loop to `i < N`.

Answer (score 1):

You also have a memory leak in callFunction2.

Comment: Because i forgot to delete the array at the end?